# How to keep login modal open after failed login in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've had problems with this for a while. After I attempt to login with wrong password, it doesn't keep me on that login modal. It opens the index page and I have to press button "login" from navbar to open the modal. Then it does give me the error message "Failed login.". But I don't want to double click everything. I need it to stay in the login modal after failed login and show the error message.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Authorize(Logins LoginModel)
        {
            var LoggedUser = db.Logins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == LoginModel.Username && x.Password == LoginModel.Password);
            if (LoggedUser != null)
            {
                //ViewBag.LoginMessage = "Login was a success!";
                ViewBag.LoggedStatus = "In";
                ViewBag.LoginError = 0; //no errors
                Session["Username"] = LoggedUser.Username;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                LoginModel.ErrorMessage = "Login failed.";
                ViewBag.LoggedStatus = "Out";
                ViewBag.LoginError = 1;
                return View("Index", LoginModel);
            }
        }
```

_LoginModal.csthml :

```
           <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
                {
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Salasana</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <label class="field-validation-error">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ErrorMessage)</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-success" value="Login" />
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                }
                <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:10px">
                </div>
            </div>
```

And on the index page I have this added so it opens the login modal:

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_LoginModal");
}
```

So I tried to do it like this and added it to the _LoginModal.csthml, but it didn't work:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            @if(ViewBag.ErrorMessage == "Wrong username/password")
            {
                WriteLiteral("$('#LoginModal').modal('show');");
            };
    </script>
}
```

I really need the help!

Comment: Have you tried to put the RenderPartial lines in an if condition? _If (ViewBag.LoginError == null || ViewBag.LoginError == 1)_

Comment: Do you mean in _LoginModal.cshtml? I tried this: 
```
@if (ViewBag.LoginError == 1)
{
    @section scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function login() {
                $('_LoginModal').modal('show');
                };
        </script>
    }
}
```
But wasn't quite sure where to call the function. Tips?

Comment: No, no script required. The idea is to just include the @HtmlPartial only when the ViewBag.LoginError is null (the first time you show the Index page) or when the ViewBag.LoginError is 1 (when the user/pass validation fails) otherwise there is no LoginModal when you call RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")

Comment: However the ViewBag is a very short lived object. If you return to the Index page you will not remember you have already validated the user. You need some more permanent storage. Session perhaps.

Comment: Oh okay I see. You mean changing this to index:
@if (ViewBag.LoginError == 1)
{
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_LoginModal");
    }
}
? But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you send the entire form to be posted back to the server. That is why entire page gets refresh.
Try `Ajax.BeginForm()` to post only `form` not the entire `page`

Create `Ajax form` (replace @html.beginform with this code)

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Authorize", "Your_Controller_Name", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess(data)",
    UpdateTargetId = "modalbody"
}, new { id = "loginForm" }))
{
    <table>...</table>
}
```

Add `OnSuccess(data)` function at the bottom of the view

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == false) {
        /*Login unsuccessful*/
        $(".field-validation-error").html(data.message);
    }
    else {
        /*Login successful*/
        $('#LoginModal').modal('hide');
        window.location.replace("/Home/Index");
    }
}
```

And last change `Authorize` action method

```
public JsonResult Authorize(Logins LoginModel)
{
    var LoggedUser = db.Logins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == LoginModel.Username && x.Password == LoginModel.Password);
    if (LoggedUser != null)
    {
        //ViewBag.LoginMessage = "Login was a success!";
        ViewBag.LoggedStatus = "In";
        ViewBag.LoginError = 0; //no errors
        Session["Username"] = LoggedUser.Username;
        return Json(new { IsSuccess = true, message = "Login successfully!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        LoginModel.ErrorMessage = "Login failed.";
        ViewBag.LoggedStatus = "Out";
        ViewBag.LoginError = 1;
        return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, message = LoginModel.ErrorMessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I did this, but every time I try to log in and give false information, then it opes a new window with nothing but this text: {
"IsSuccess": false,
"message": "Login failed."
} ... Same window if username and password it right, but "IsSuccess: true". So it didn't work yet. :/

Comment: This is because you did'nt add the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script file. Resolution 1) Install nuget `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` package. 2) Add this script inside view 3) Open `webconfig` under `appsetting` add `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`